# Emulator crashes when ran in a container

Tags: android, docker, android-emulator

I have a Flutter app that I want to get screenshots from in various devices.
I have a CI server that runs GitLab.

My procedure would be

- start emulator (phone, small tablet, large tablet)
- build APK
- install APK
- start activity with intent extra to show a specific portion of the app
- screenshot
- rinse & repeat for all screenshots I want
- save images as artifcats

That works but this is a bit heavy on the server. I have to maintain and use 3 emulators on the server, which uses a lot of CPU and RAM for nothing outside of CI builds.

I tried to embed the list above in a `cirrusci/flutter` container. That works, but now the emulator crashes for no obvious reason.

I dumped the logcat, it seems that before crashing it's related to OpenGL, but that may just be a coincidence.
I enabled core dumps, the emulator stops with a SIGSEGV.

All emulators, images, SDK, etc are up to date. I'm running this on Debian 11 (bullseye) on a HP DL380 (no graphical card but KVM and GPU drivers are up to date).

There is no RAM issue, as the server has 10GB RAM and 30GB swap (NVMe) free (or cached by the kernel). Ditto for disk.

I'm starting the emulator with:

```
emulator "@$dev" -no-boot-anim -no-window -no-audio -no-snapshot -read-only &
```

`$dev` is the name of my emulator. The GitLab runner has volume mounts for the `$HOME/.android` directory and the Android SDK directory (both are installed on the host to avoid re-download on each build).
This is reproducible with:

```
docker run --rm -ti -v /opt/gradle-caches:/root/.gradle/caches -v $HOME/.android:/root/.android -v /opt/android:/opt/android-sdk-linux --privileged cirrusci/flutter bash
```

Why would it crash inside a container but not on the host?

What makes it crash is almost always (but not 100%): `adb exec-out screencap -p`. I also tried with the regular `adb screencap -p /sdcard/img.png` but that's the same result.

Edit to add another example (device offline happened just after the emulator SIGSEGV'd):

```
adb -H 192.168.0.14 -P 5038 -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop my.app.pkg
adb: device offline
```

It can manage to make 1 or 2 screenshots but crashes rapidly. I'd like to have 5-7 screenshots per emulator.

Edit to add the `emulator ... -verbose` output when it dies:

```
VERBOSE | Data frame has invalid ether type 0
VERBOSE | Unexpected ether type: 0. Dump frame: Data (Data)
    :
```

Edit: the exit code is 139 (don't know if it's the OS or qemu.

I switched back to emulators running on hosts and containers interfacing to them over TCP (adb), but now even the host emulators crash. I don't get it. Might need a reboot... :-/

Edit: tried with https://github.com/google/android-emulator-container-scripts — same error but more logs:

```
logcat: 03-30 02:28:07.231  2267  2629 I OpaEligibilityChecker: send OpaEligibilityChange broadcast to CommonBroadcastReceiver
2023/03/30 02:28:56 socat[135] W read(5, 0x55847839d8a0, 8192): Connection reset by peer
2023/03/30 02:28:57 socat[715] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:5557, 16): Connection refused
2023/03/30 02:28:57 socat[716] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:5557, 16): Connection refused
2023/03/30 02:28:57 socat[717] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:5557, 16): Connection refused
2023/03/30 02:28:57 socat[718] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:5557, 16): Connection refused
```

Comment: I was able to semi-work around this by using blunt force. Every time I want to make a screenshot, I make sure the emu is live, start the app, take screenshot. The pipeline went from 9 to 25 minutes :-(

Comment: Note for comment above (after solution was found): that didn't work. The issue was clearly a race condition depending on how fast the network was loading the image, and how slow was the emulator to redraw the scene. Indeed, if the emulator was swamped and the network fast, the image could load before flutter rendered the layout tree, and since it had the image, it didn't display the skeleton and didn't crash. If the emulator was fast or network slow, flutter had the chance to render the layout tree before having the image, so it rendered the skeleton, and boom.

Answer (score 0):

After trying on old builds and moving up the git tree with dichotomies, I was able to find the commit that had the breaking change. It was caused by a flutter network image that used a skeleton during download. Reverting it to a circular progress indicator fixed the issue:

```
 class MyNetworkImageWrapper extends CachedNetworkImage {
   MyNetworkImageWrapper(String imageUrl, {super.key, bool isThumbnail = false})
       : super(
           imageUrl: getImage(imageUrl, isThumbnail),
-          placeholder: (context, url) => SkeletonAvatar(
-            style: SkeletonAvatarStyle(
-              width: double.infinity,
-              minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 8,
-              maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
-            ),
-          ),
-        );
+          placeholder: (context, url) => const SizedBox(
+                height: 32.0,
+                width: 32.0,
+                child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.tealAccent),
+              ));
 }
```

I can't believe that this skeleton thing causes a flutter crash that kills the emu. I guess that since flutter draws every pixel, they use native code to do so, and said native bug has a crash that SIGSEGVs and causes the emu to crash. I don't understand how this is possible, flutter native code is userland, so crashing should just crash the app. It feels like it crashes PID 1 or the kernel for the emulator to completely stop abruptly.

I don't consider this fixed, but at least I have a workaround. What's odd is that on my device it works fine (with the skeleton).

Comment: https://github.com/badjio/skeletons/issues/4